# Finding method def for error signature on Windows XP SP3 PC

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-xp-sp3, ildasm

I am trying to find the System.dll file to open with ILDASM.exe and find the method definition and offset and see why my application is crashing on Windows XP machines only. Am I trying to open the correct dll for this assembly listed in this error signature? I'm looking in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5 at System.Core.dll because it has the System namespace in it when opened by ILDASM.exe.

The same program runs just fine on a windows 7 PC.

I have the following Error signature from attempting to run my application on a Windows XP machine with service pack 3.

```
Error signature
  EventType: clr20r3
  P1: myapplication.exe                 >Is the exe file name
  P2: 1.0.0.0                           >Is the exe file assembly version number
  P3: 51e6a3d8                          >Is the exe file stamp
  P4: system                            >Is the faulting assembly full name
  P5: 4.0.0.0                           >Is the faulting assembly version
  P6: 5073c71b                          >Is the faulting assembly timestamp
  P7: 3d57                              >Is the faulting assembly method def
  P8: bd                                >Is faulting method IL Offset within the faulting method
  P9: system.invalidoperationexception  >Exception type that was thrown
```

Comment: Just for fun, what's the line of code you're executing in your application that spawns the InvalidOperationException?  (Not to mention the exception message if there is one)

Comment: I have no idea what line it is in my application. This is the only message I'm able to get from the client's XP machine. It doesn't happen on my dev Windows 7 machine. I'm trying to figure out what method in the `system` assembly it is faulting on by going off of this error signature because that is the only thing I have to go off of.

Comment: This article is where I'm getting the P1, P2 etc. descriptions from, and how to find the method definition and offset with ILDASM.exe http://naveensrinivasan.com/2010/11/16/clr20r3/ I just don't know if I'm opening the correct .dll file.

Comment: If you can get a full stack trace (possibly by giving the client an updated version) you'll be a lot better off.  Even if it's a release mode stack trace with no line numbers, you can still probably figure out which line of your code is causing the problem.  You'll have a much easier time understanding what's going on starting from knowledge of your own code rather than trying to dig into a very complicated and obfuscated library written by another company.  Is this information coming out of a mini dump by any chance?  If not, where'd you get it?